# How to use joomla login to be authenticated from an external webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, joomla3.0

I have developped a web service using .Net framework and it will get the login details such as user name and password. when login is clicked it has to request web service using rest and get authenticated. since i failed, I have created a joomla module (custom html) a login form and i tried again by editing the html code and couldnt find a way to communicate with my web service. please help me. any way of doing this? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication process in Joomla! is managed by plugin rather than modules.
In fact, you have to write a plugin, which `extends JPlugin`, and overwrite the function  `onUserAuthenticate( $credentials, $options, &$response )`

The relevant piece of code, where you log in the user if authenticated by some other authority (webservice, database, and so on), is where you set the status of a specific user (identified by username) this way:

```
$response = JUser::getInstance(); 
$response->username = $credentials['username'];         
$response->fullname =  $fullname;
$response->email = $email;
$response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_SUCCESS;
$message = JText::_('JGLOBAL_AUTH_ACCESS_GRANTED');
return true;
```

Documentation at http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5:Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla is still useful.

Since you didn't provide code (and debug output) it's hard to find out what went wrong with webservice.